# asp.net customer information class

Tags: asp.net

I am building a asp.net web application (framework 4) and wanted to developed a class that holds basic customer information (customer id, email, phone, address info, customer accounts etc) which should be 
available to access through out the website pages so that I don't have store customer id some where (session etc) and make call to DB whenever I need some info about that customer.
I wanted to make a call to DB only once when users logs in to portal and get his/her basic info and store it in form of a class.

can any one tell how to develope such type fo class and where/how to store it to make it avail to all the pages?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how classes work, especially with regard to persistence. Mainly, classes are persistence-ignorant. HTTP protocol is stateless by its nature, so once a request is completed your class instance will be destroyed. You will need to use Session (or some other persistence mechanism) at some point to store your customer information (even if it is a class object).

Comment: ASP.NET pages are stateless. Global information needs to be stored somewhere. Session is not bad to use if you use it correctly. If you want to minimize what's in Session, simply store the user's ID (or whatever unique identifier you have), and when you need information about that customer, go get it from the database.

Comment: I totally agree with Brian, from your question it seems your missing how object oriented programming works.

Answer (score 0):

Once user successfully logged in, make a single call to DB to retrieve the current `Customer` object and save it to the `Session`. Don't just think that you will be misusing the server's memory. The object would be less than 500 bytes and if you have 1000 live sessions it's just less than 500 KB of your server's memory.

You may also consider `Cache` typed to `User ID` and retrieve `Customer` object along.

You may also save the `Customer` object to `ViewState` and that wouldn't take any memory on the server.

It's very easy to access `Session`\ `Cache`\ `ViewState` from any page.

**For `Session`**:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Customer customer = Session["customer"] as Customer;
}

private void LoginSuccess(int customerID) {
    Customer customer = _customerRepository.GetById(customerID);
    Session["customer"] = customer;
}
```

**For `ViewState`, it's just same as `Session` - just replace `Session` with `ViewState`.

If you want to store it in `Cache` then use

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("customer" + customerId, customer, new CacheDependency("customer" + customerId), Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

And you can access the `Cache` item like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache["customer" + customerID]
```

Hope this helps!